# Mouse Hover not working as expected on SVG

Tags: css, svg

I have created SVG using illustrator, now I am using CSS for mouse hover effects.

The mouse hover stop working on parent element when it is hovered on the child element. I can't get to know why is it? Is it because the child elements are preventing the propogation of hover effect?

Here is the relevant SVG group:

```
<a target="_blank" href="#">
        <g id="Technology">
            <defs>
                <rect id="SVGID_1_" x="191.825" y="377.344" width="37.1" height="33.539"/>
            </defs>
            <clipPath id="SVGID_2_">
                <use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  overflow="visible"/>
            </clipPath>

            <path class="pie-chunk" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M280.676 ....."/>
            <path class="small-chunk" fill="#1387C9" d="M136.448,339.175c21.922,58.945,78.01,10...."></path>
            <path class="pie-chunk" clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M225.97,381.062h-9.865 ..."/>
            <path class="pie-chunk"  clip-path="url(#SVGID_2_)" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M202.123,394.549v4 .... "/>

            <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 100.6704 465)" fill="#39A4DC" font-size="16">
           TECHNOLOGY
</text>
        </g>
    </a>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    g#Technology:hover text tspan,
    g#Technology:hover text{
        fill: #fff;
    } 
    g#Technology:hover .pie-chunk:hover{
        fill: #5D5D5D;
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
    g#Technology:hover .small-chunk{
        fill: #1E3565;
    }
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fupa5u9p/) to the problem.

To produce:

1. Hover over the Technology White Section, it will work fine.
2. Hover over the text (child element), it will make the hover effect
   go weird.
3. Hover over the blue small section with icon, it will again go weird.

Can anyone please point me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you fix your JSFiddle link, please?

Comment: You probably need to add `pointer-events: none;` to the CSS rules for the text element and the "blue small section with icon" (whatever the hell that is). But without a [mcve] — or at the very least a link to your JSFiddle page — it's impossible to be sure what your problem is. Please either fix this question or delete it.

Comment: Sorry. @VTodorov here is the link https://jsfiddle.net/fupa5u9p/

Comment: @squeamishossifrage sorry I just updated the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is with your CSS.

```
g#Technology:hover .pie-chunk:hover{
    fill: #5D5D5D;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

You are either hovering the parent or the child, not both.  Remove the second `:hover` and I think it will behave how you were expecting.

```css
.svg-wrapper {
     background: #ccc;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0 auto;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     position: absolute;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
 .svg-wrapper text,
 .svg-wrapper tspan{
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: 700;

 }
 .small-chunk,
 .pie-chunk{
  transition: 0.8s;
 }
 
 
 g#Technology:hover text tspan,
 g#Technology:hover text {
  fill: #fff;
 } 
 g#Technology:hover .pie-chunk {
  fill: #5D5D5D;
  opacity: 0.9;
 }
```

```html
<div class="svg-wrapper">
 <svg id="Layer_1" width="570.049px" height="569.001px" viewBox="0 0 570.049 569.001">
 <a target="_blank" href="http://headsinternational.com/focus/technology">
  <g id="Technology">
   <path class="pie-chunk" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M280.676,528.176l-0.049-46.825l-0.016-17.363l-0.023-21.567c-66.187-1.626-122.278-43.901-144.2-102.843
    l-20.589,6.416l-16.972,5.292l-44.135,13.762l-39.215,12.225c38.068,110.46,142.233,190.113,265.238,191.729L280.676,528.176z"/>
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 100.6704 465)" fill="#39A4DC" font-family="'OpenSans-Extrabold'" font-size="16">TECHNOLOGY</text>
  </g>
 </a>

  </svg>
</div>
```